Spring Application: CAS v7.0.0: Intermittent Deadlock on restart
I have recently migrated my application from CAS v6.6.2 to v7.0.0 I am facing the issues during the restart. It intermittently gets stuck and we get a deadlock in the thread dump.
We have tried various solution, setting the lazy initialization to false.
Creating a filter to revoke all the request during startup, even tried to delay the dispatcher Servlet initialization. but it didn't help.
What we suspect is that the combination of @RefreshScope and @Lazy annotation creating issues, which is being widely used in CAS v7.0.0.
We came to the above conclusion due to an issue mentioned in the spring repo. On this bug there is a file attached which also have the exact same deadlock.
RefreshScopeDeadLock.zip.
Thread dump stacktrace:
Found one Java-level deadlock:
=============================
"Thread-10":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x000000001fec2c78 (object 0x000000076fd80250, a java.lang.String),
  which is held by "Thread-5"
"Thread-5":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x000000001be39628 (object 0x000000076fd7ba88, a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap),
  which is held by "Thread-10"

Java stack information for the threads listed above:
===================================================
"Thread-10":
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:380)
    - waiting to lock <0x000000076fd80250> (a java.lang.String)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:183)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at my.project.name.RefreshScopeDeadLock$FakeSampler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$212b6f8d.doSomething(<generated>)
    at my.project.name.RefreshScopeDeadLock$InCreationBean.accessFakesampler(RefreshScopeDeadLock.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1694)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$8/556529265.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    - locked <0x000000076fd7ba88> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1015)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1107)
    at my.project.name.RefreshScopeDeadLock.lambda$0(RefreshScopeDeadLock.java:27)
    at my.project.name.RefreshScopeDeadLock$$Lambda$57/1367937032.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
"Thread-5":
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:185)
    - waiting to lock <0x000000076fd7ba88> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:427)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:470)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$59/1420933976.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:382)
    - locked <0x000000076fd80250> (a java.lang.String)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:183)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at my.project.name.RefreshScopeDeadLock$FakeSampler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$212b6f8d.doSomething(<generated>)
    at my.project.name.RefreshScopeDeadLock$AlreadyCreatedBean.accessFakesampler(RefreshScopeDeadLock.java:85)
    at my.project.name.RefreshScopeDeadLock$$Lambda$56/575935098.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Found 1 deadlock.

Is there any solution to it?
